# Confusion about Synthesis Results of Verilog Code: DATAIN has no connection

Tags: digital-logic, latch, quartus

I am quite puzzled about the synthesis results of the following code.

Here is the code:

```vhdl
module IntentionalLatch(Din, CS, WR, Dout);
    input CS, WR; // CS: chip select, active low
    input Din;
    output Dout;
    reg Dout;
    always @(CS or WR or Din)
        if (!CS)
            if (WR)
                Dout=Din;
            else
                Dout=Dout;
        else
            Dout=1'bz;
endmodule
```

The synthesis result (viewed with RTL viewer, Quartus ii 18.0) is:

[image: RTL viewer]

I don't understand why the DATAIN input port of latch Dout_14 is not connected to anything. In this case, what should be the output of Dout_14 when CS = 0? I wonder if it is really a normal latch that I know. Is there any way to get detailed description of a node in RTL viewer including its input/output ports, its behavioural in Quartus ii?

Comment: @toolic I run a behavioural simulation and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be tied internally to presumably a logic 1.

When `CS` is high, the latch will be cleared to 0, setting the `Dout` output buffer to high-z (`OE` low).

When `CS` goes low, if `WR` is low, the latch will hold the current value of 0 keeping the output high-z (`Dout = Dout`).

With `CS` low, when `WR` is high, the latch will load a value of 1 (the data in for the latch is tied high), which will drive OE high, enabling out output buffer. The output buffer will then take whatever value is stored in the other latch.

The only reason/source that will make the `OE` signal go low again in your code is if the `CS` pin goes high. That can be accomplished by the `aclr` input already being used, so there is no need for the data in to the output enable latch to ever be anything but high.

Comment: Thank you! And still have a question, can I assume that in the RTL viewer, any unconnected input port is considered to be 1?

Comment: @Tokubara no, they could be unconnected or 0. To view the values, you can either click on the block and view its properties - this should list `Fan In` and `Fan Out` info. Or there should be a button for "Show Unconnected Pins" which may also work to show it connected to a constant.

Comment: @Tokubara hmm, doesn't seem to show it because it's a primitive, and the RTL viewer "Hides default connections such as VCC and GND." to ["maximize readability"](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683230/18-1/maximizing-readability-in-rtl-viewer.html) - whilst also making things more difficult to understand. I think in this case it is safe to assume that if the data in is not shown, and the aclr pin is, that the data in is connected high.